# How do I iterate over a an array of objects that live inside another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, video.js

I am using a plugin on video.js called videojs-overlay. This allows me to add overlays to a single video inside a playlist.

I now want to extend this functionality to allow for different overlays to appear on different videos (these are defined inside a method). I can't figure out what the issue is with this. How do I iterate over this object to access each overlay on different videos in the playlist?

**player.playlist() method - defining the different videos:**

```
player.playlist([{
    name: 'Video 1',
    overlays: [{
            content: '<div class="overlay-1a"></div>',
            showBackground: false,
            start: 'pause',
            end: 'play',
            align: 'left-middle'
        },
        {
            content: '<div class="overlay-1b"></div>',
            showBackground: false,
            start: 'pause',
            end: 'play',
            align: 'right-middle'
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Video 2',
    overlays: [{
            content: '<div class="overlay-2a"></div>',
            showBackground: false,
            start: 'pause',
            end: 'play',
            align: 'left-middle'
        },
        {
            content: '<div class="overlay-2b"></div>',
            showBackground: false,
            start: 'pause',
            end: 'play',
            align: 'right-middle'
        }
    ]
}
]);
```

**Code for the event when the video in the playlist changes:** I want the overlays to update in this event and it should iterate over each one in each video. This isn't working for some reason

```
  player.on('playlistitem', function (event, video) {
    player.playlist().overlays.forEach(function () {
      player.overlay({
        content: video.content,
        showBackground: video.showBackground,
        start: video.start,
        end: video.end,
        align: video.align,
        class: video.class
      });
    });
```

Comment: You should assign the array to a variable, so you can access the array by this variable name.

Comment: @enf0rcer That doesn't answer the question...

Comment: What happens in your code? It looks like in the top snippet that you are passing an array of videos with nested overlays into the playlist.  In your event it looks like you are treating the play list as though it contains a single video.  Do you know how to use chrome developer tools F12?  debugger; on the first line of your event handler and then debug through and look at what player.playlist() returns. If it returns an array as I suspect then you would need to do a  player.playlist().forEach to loop over the videos.

Comment: @Andrew That's right, passing an array of videos with nested overlays (one video can have multiple overlays on the video).  player.playlist() returns all the indexes in the array. However, the event 'playlistitem' only fires when the next video starts playing, so imagine if the overlays weren't in an array... it works fine. As soon as I put it inside an array theres issues accessing the overlays

Comment: @zxynz did you try adding the debugger line to and opening the dev tools to debug and see what the player.playlist() returns? Or add console.log(JSON.stringify(player.playlist()); and look in the console?

Comment: @Andrew, yeah, that returns the whole object (as string if stringify is used). Also,   console.log(player.playlist()[0].overlays); returns the 2 overlays present in the first index

Comment: Have  you tried player.playlist()[0].overlays. Notice [0]... This will assume the first video.

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you are after

```
  player.on('playlistitem', function (event, video) {
    player.playlist().forEach(function(video) {
      video.overlays.forEach(function (overlay) {
        overlay({
          content: video.content,
          showBackground: video.showBackground,
          start: video.start,
          end: video.end,
          align: video.align,
          class: video.class
        });
      })
    });
```

Loop over each video and then for each video loop over each overlay and update the overlay. Or maybe this...

```
  player.on('playlistitem', function (event, video) {
    var playlist =player.playlist();
     playlist = playlist.map(function(video) {
      video.overlays.map(function (overlay) {
        overlay({
          content: video.content,
          showBackground: video.showBackground,
          start: video.start,
          end: video.end,
          align: video.align,
          class: video.class
        });
      });
      player.playlist(playlist);
    });
```